# Can we search for posts with links to specific domains?

Tags: support, spam, search

I flagged yet another spammer today, and found she had an older post that got by. This annoys me, since I want them gone and burninated like forgotten toast

SU and SE as a whole lets us search for text strings in posts - I notice that a few sites spam constantly and I figure if I can search for posts with links to them, I should be able to search for posts that link to example.com and get them. A search for spammysite.com will give me questions that have that string, but not embedded links with another text - something like "oh you can find an answer [here](http://example.com)".

Can we have the latter case searchable so we can better hunt for spam, or questions referencing specific sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching with `url:*example.com*` will search for all posts containing the above URL, even if it is embedded

Comment: Nice. This should increase my efficiency at spammer flagging :)

Comment: With the changes to the search engine lately, wild cards aren't needed anymore